# Is it valid to calculate the value of a Big O notation?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Is it valid to calculate the value of a given Big O notation? What i mean is, will the number that you get by calculating a given Big O notation always correspond to the exact maximum number of steps that an algorithm has to perform?

As an example, suppose we have a sorting algorithm with the efficiency of O(n log n), then if we know that the size of N is 8, then could we do:
**8x log2(8) = 24**, and so the maximum number of steps required for the algorithm, given that N is 8, will be 24

Comment: If you want the number of steps, derive a formula for it. Big OH is about comparing time complexity in general, it's not a precise measure at N, rather an asymptotic as N grows large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no point in this, because

a) it is an asymptotic measure, that only describes the growth of the output as the input grows towards infinity

b) it ignores constant offsets and constant multipliers (which completely makes any concrete numbers useless).